# How to set default time (0:00:00) in Date-Time control of Dialog Editor using VC++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am developing an application using VC++ where there is a dialog and into the dialog have a Date-Time Control. When the dialog load, the date time control shows current date and time.

But I would like to change the time to 0:00:00 by default when the dialog loads.

Can anyone have any suggestion about this?

Note: Have googled but still no luck.
IDE Version: Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Its a WinAPI project

Comment: Yes, its not MFC application.
Just for Reference, I can get the time by following line:
`GetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_DATETIMEPICKER_FROM_TIME, mDateTimeFromTime, 80);`

Comment: And what exactly are you having problems with? It's not like initializing a dialog is an unsolved problem.

Comment: The problem is (as I wrote in the post) I want to set default time to '0:00:00' while loading the dialog, not the system time. But How can I do that?

Comment: And I explained, that initializing a dialog is a solved issue. It's hard to guess, what you are having trouble with. Unless you explain *exactly*, what it is that you are having difficulty with, this question is neither helpful nor answerable, and needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just initialize the control to whatever state you want in WM_INITDIALOG:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>

...

INT_PTR CALLBACK MyDialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM)
{
  switch(Msg)
  {
  case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
      SYSTEMTIME st;
      HWND hDT = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_MYDATETIMECONTROL);
      if (GDT_VALID == SendMessage(hDT, DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME, NULL, (LPARAM) &st)) // Calling DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME to get the current date.
      {
        st.wHour = st.wMinute = st.wSecond = st.wMilliseconds = 0;
        SendMessage(hDT, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, GDT_VALID, (LPARAM) &st);
      }
    }
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```